# Should street numbers be written as cardinal or ordinal numbers

Tags: numbers

When writing a numerical street, do you use a cardinal number (220 Street) or ordinal number (220th Street)

Comment: It depends on the actual name of the street. Nearly all streets named with numbers are named with ordinal numbers, but I am sure there are a few named "two street" and "five street" somewhere in the world. (And some in English-speaking countries are even named with Spanish numbers.)

Comment: I find it hard to believe any town/city planners could be so unimaginative as to have over two hundred *streets* (or *avenues*, or whatever) that they couldn't be bothered to think of names for. But *Fifth Avenue* is always ordinal - I never heard of anything like *Five Avenue*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the crappy little podunk known as [Manhattan](https://www.google.com/maps/place/W+220th+St,+New+York,+NY+10034/@40.8721294,-73.9122571,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c2f38d599b37f9:0xc3de3284aaa688c7), New York City.

Comment: @Digital Chris: Wow! Every tin-pot local councillor in Britain would weep to see a road that could have been named in his honour being wasted on an unappreciative *number!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: there's a *"Five Road"* in Carmel, Maine. But cardinal-number streets are incredibly rare.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: some of the numbered avenues in New York actually have names (*6th Avenue* is officially *Avenue of the Americas*). But people still call them by their numbers.

Comment: @Peter: Would-be cab drivers in Lomdon have their work cut out acquiring [*"The Knowledge"*](http://www.theknowledgetaxi.co.uk/) (though even before satnav, I never had any problem using my [London A to Z](http://www.amazon.co.uk/London-Street-Atlas-spiral-A-Z/dp/1843486032)), but they certainly shouldn't have a problem in New York. I'm always hearing about *5th Avenue* and *42nd Street*, but I never stopped to think that by implication there must be *hundreds* of such names. To me, it seems a bit like christening your children *First Baby, Second Baby*, etc.

Comment: The avenues run north-south, and there are only 11 of them. The streets run east-west, and there are indeed hundreds. But this means it's much easier locating addresses in New York than in London.

Answer (score 1):

The US Post Office web site will standardize an address with such a street to the ordinal version. So at least for addressing an envelope to an American recipient, the answer is ordinal.

Having said that, I should mentioned an exception. In some rural areas, otherwise-unnamed roads are numbered consecutively. In these cases, the word 'Road' *precedes* the number, e.g., Zillow has a record for

```
26180 County Road 97
Davis, CA 95616
```

(This is not my home; I found it with Google knowing the roads in that area. Road 98 is nearby.)

Miami's Calle Ocho, home of the Cuban community, is not an official Post Office designation AFAIK.

Comment: Cardinal number after is also used for state highways, US routes, and Interstate highways, e.g. I-95, Route 66, and the 505.